# Jenkins deploy to webshpere without websphere deployment plugin

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, websphere, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to deploy from jenkins to websphere 8.5 ND without the websphere deployment plugin ?

Do I need to install websphere on the jenkins server in order to use the wsadmin scripting tool  or there is a way I can only install the wsadmin cli ?

This is a remote deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wsadmin thin client .

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/txml_adminclient.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is still relevant, but you can do it with websphere auto deployment.
You can find more in the link below:
https://studylib.net/doc/18267118/monitored-deployment-auto-deployment

The flow should look something like this.

**Enable monitored directory on Websphere server:**

[image]

1. Click Applications > Global deployment settings. To enable monitored directory deployment, select Monitor directory to automatically deploy applications. Ensure that the directory that you specified for Monitored directory exists. The product does not create the directory for you. To change the polling interval, specify the number of seconds for Polling interval.
2. Click Apply.
3. Restart the application server.

**Result**
The product sets monitored directory deployment attributes to the values that you specified.

**What to do next**
If you enabled monitored directory deployment, deploy your applications by adding files to a monitored directory.

This step is based on your Jenkins application. If your Jenkins instance running on the same server as applications, just copy files after build to the monitored folder. If it's not you may use SSH plugins to push files to monitored directory.

Comment: Can you add more instruction to this answer rather than just relying on the link?

Comment: @Druckles, added instructions how to setup server for autodeploy